# Соединить две таблицы в базе данных особенным образом

Tags: oracle, sql, postgresql, mysql

Есть одна таблица date_table со столбцами

```
id, date, note
```

и вторая currency_table со столбцами

```
num_code, ch_code, name, rate
```

И, в общем, ежедневно в таблицу date_table будет добавляться новая запись, и к ней должна, соответственно, привязываться таблица currency_table с таблицей курс валют по соответвующей дате.

Я знаю способ, что можно создать поле в таблице date и через него привязываться к таблице date_table. Но можно ли это сделать без отображения колонки date в currency_table?

Comment: Почему бы вам не связать записи по id?

Comment: @ua6xh, краткость - сестра таланта ))

Comment: @BOPOH не без этого=)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого предназначены суррогатные ключи. Если грубо - в date_table создаете автоинкрементное поле id, а в currency_table добавляете поле date_id - в нем будете хранить значение id из date_table.

Тогда, кроме разбивки по дате, можно будет дополнительно разбивать, например, и по местам: в Москве вчера курс был 30 долларов за рубль, а во Владивостоке за рубль давали 50 долларов.

Для этого в date_table добавите дополнительно место, и все будет сделано.